# Why does implementsERC165InterfaceNoCache in ERC1820 make three calls?

Tags: erc1820

Looking at this function in ERC1820:

```
function implementsERC165InterfaceNoCache(address _contract, bytes4 _interfaceId) public view returns (bool) {
    uint256 success;
    uint256 result;

    (success, result) = noThrowCall(_contract, ERC165ID);
    if (success == 0 || result == 0) {
        return false;
    }

    (success, result) = noThrowCall(_contract, INVALID_ID);
    if (success == 0 || result != 0) {
        return false;
    }

    (success, result) = noThrowCall(_contract, _interfaceId);
    if (success == 1 && result == 1) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

My question is, why don't we directly just call the general function like we do to check the implementation instead of doing these three different calls?

What is the significance of these three if statements??

Answer (score 1):

The first two calls are the standard process to identify if the destination contract supports ERC165 correctly; you can see the description of the flow in the [official ERC165 doc](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-165#how-to-detect-if-a-contract-implements-erc-165), but as a summary:

- the first call checks if the function `supportsInterface(bytes4 interfaceID)` exists
- the second call checks if
  `supportsInterface(0xffffff)` returns `false`

The third call is to test if the destination contract supports the specified `_interfaceId`.

As a *non-mandatory design choice*, you check for ERC165 support before the third call because you pay potentially much more gas in case of failure - that is, the contract does not support ERC165, so your tentative checking for support of the interface results in an exception and you lose all the gas attached to the tx - versus the added cost of successfully operating the two first calls.